# Multipage PDF does not open on iPad

Tags: c#, ios, ipad, pdf

I am working with a project where I am generating PDF Files from PSR Files. The PDF Files works fine if its a single page but if It has more than two PSR Files and I generate two files it does not open on iPad and works fine on Desktop.

The Third library tool I am using here is 'dbatuotrack' and I am using C#.

Can anyone please guide me how to resolve this problem?

Thanks,
S.

```
        foreach (var pdfform in pdfPagesID)
        {
            //dbAutoTrack.PDFWriter.Document objDoc = null;
            //dbAutoTrack.PDFWriter.Page objPage = null;

            objDoc = new dbAutoTrack.PDFWriter.Document();


            pdfPagesID.Clear();
            pdfPagesID = GetSpecPageID(pdfform);

            if (pdfPagesID.Count > 1)
            {
                foreach (var pdfPage in pdfPagesID)
                {
                    dbAutoTrack.PDFWriter.Page objPage2 = null;
                    var lastItem = pdfPagesID.Last();
                    prefixPageID = prefixSpecPageID(pdfPage);
                    suffixPageIDPSR = prefixPageID + ".psr";
                    if (File.Exists(PSRPath + suffixPageIDPSR))
                    {
                        objDs = new CDatasheet(this.PSRPath + suffixPageIDPSR, false);
                        objDs.pdfDbHelper = pdfhelper;
                        //Giving the specformId as SpecFornName
                       pdfFormName = "Form" + pdfform + ".pdf";
                        if (!(pdfPage == pdfPagesID.First()))
                        {

                            objPage2 = objDs.Generate_PDFReport();
                            objDoc.Pages.Add(objPage2);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            objPage = objDs.Generate_PDFReport();
                            objDoc.Pages.Add(objPage);
                        }
                        if (objPage != null)
                        {
                            if (pdfWithNotePage == true && pdfPage.Equals(lastItem))
                            {
                                objNotePage = objDs.GetNotePage();
                                objDoc.Pages.Add(objPage);
                                objDoc.Pages.Add(objNotePage);

                            }
                            else
                            {

                                //objDoc.Pages.Add(objPage);
                                //objDoc.Pages.Add(objPage2);
                            }
                            fsOutput = new FileStream(TemplatePath + pdfFormName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                            objDoc.Generate(fsOutput);


                        }
                        if (fsOutput != null)
                        {
                            fsOutput.Close();
                            fsOutput.Dispose();
                            fsOutput = null;
                        }
                    }

                }
                objDoc = null;
                objPage = null;
            }
```

Comment: ok the difference in the platform(s) should be a dead give away for starters.. what is the `OS` for `IPad vs DeskTop` does IPad support .NET framework.. I don't think so unless you are using a VM from my understanding.. have you consulted with the 3rd party library support documentation to see if they have any C# .NET examples that will work for the `OS x.xx` version of IPad

Comment: For desktop, I am using windows environment and if a file has more than two files it does not open. it works open if I open a single document.

Comment: perhaps you should debug this when you have 2 documents or more and step thru the code ..you are obviously doing something wrong could be that you are clearing or resetting something where you least expect it.. I would suggest stepping thru the code

Comment: @DJ KRAZE, Thanks so much for your input. This lines "you are obviously doing something wrong could be that you are clearing or resetting something where you least expect it.." were bang on. I went back and go through the code, figured out that I was disposing the output after adding the pages to the document.

Comment: glad that I pointed the not so obvious to you.. this is why debugging is so important

Answer (score 1):

This how I tweaked the code to make it work.  Thanks for the suggestion DJ KRAZE

```
    foreach (var pdfform in pdfPagesID)
    {
        //dbAutoTrack.PDFWriter.Document objDoc = null;
        //dbAutoTrack.PDFWriter.Page objPage = null;

        objDoc = new dbAutoTrack.PDFWriter.Document();


        pdfPagesID.Clear();
        pdfPagesID = GetSpecPageID(pdfform);

        if (pdfPagesID.Count > 1)
        {
            foreach (var pdfPage in pdfPagesID)
            {
                dbAutoTrack.PDFWriter.Page objPage2 = null;
                var lastItem = pdfPagesID.Last();
                prefixPageID = prefixSpecPageID(pdfPage);
                suffixPageIDPSR = prefixPageID + ".psr";
                if (File.Exists(PSRPath + suffixPageIDPSR))
                {
                    objDs = new CDatasheet(this.PSRPath + suffixPageIDPSR, false);
                    objDs.pdfDbHelper = pdfhelper;
                    //Giving the specformId as SpecFornName
                   pdfFormName = "Form" + pdfform + ".pdf";
                    if (!(pdfPage == pdfPagesID.First()))
                    {

                        objPage2 = objDs.Generate_PDFReport();
                        objDoc.Pages.Add(objPage2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        objPage = objDs.Generate_PDFReport();
                        objDoc.Pages.Add(objPage);
                    }
                    if (objPage != null)
                    {
                        if (pdfWithNotePage == true && pdfPage.Equals(lastItem))
                        {
                            objNotePage = objDs.GetNotePage();
                            objDoc.Pages.Add(objPage);
                            objDoc.Pages.Add(objNotePage);

                        }
                        else
                        {

                            //objDoc.Pages.Add(objPage);
                            //objDoc.Pages.Add(objPage2);
                        }
     }
    }
    }
                        fsOutput = new FileStream(TemplatePath + pdfFormName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                        objDoc.Generate(fsOutput);


                     //This region was the problem, disposing the output everytime.
                //Needed it to be included after completion of iteration
                    if (fsOutput != null)
                    {
                        fsOutput.Close();
                        fsOutput.Dispose();
                        fsOutput = null;
                    }
                 }
```